# CMD ignores % sign in batch file - why?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parameters, cmd

I found this command for looping all directories in the current folder:

```
FOR /D %G in ("assets\*") DO echo %G
```

It works when I type it into `CMD`, but when I save it in a `test.bat` and run the file, I get:

```
C:\Projects>test.bat
G was unexpected at this time.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch files you have to use `%%` instead. That is because a single percent is used for command-line arguments to the batch file and for environment variables. The parser is not very good, so we have to escape percent signs for `for` variables.

This is also documented in `help for` in the third paragraph:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (I'll accept your answer when SO lets me... it says I have to wait a while)